# Русские буквы из базы данных MySQL некорректно отображаются, вопреки указанным кодировкам

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, перекодировка

Сделал у себя на локальном сервере сайт на php и базу данных mysql. В БД хранятся записи на русском, украинском и английском языках. В php-скриптах тоже. Затем залил на сервер. На сервере из скриптов буквы отображаются нормально, а из БД криво (кроме латиницы). Пробовал определять кодировку, определилось как `ISO-8859-1`. Чего только не делал. Указывал заголовок

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

В БД указано `utf_general_ci`, файлы в `utf-8` без bom.

Ничего не помогает, всё равно кракозябры.

Comment: А сам файл сохранен в utf-8 ?

Comment: да, в utf-8 без bom

Comment: После подключения к БД, выполните запрос "SET NAMES utf8"

Comment: Да, такой запрос указан. Забыл сказать. Может я его неправильно указываю: mysqli_query($cdb,"SET NAMES utf8"); Может надо mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");

Comment: Если все и везде стоит "использовать UTF-8", значит вы в саму базу сохранили "кракозябры". Попробуйте проверить контент

Comment: Для mysql**i** вроде как есть [определенная функция][1] для таких целей

   [1]:http://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.set-charset.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` // пишите всегда utf8. IE не понимает `utf-8`.
2. `<meta charset="utf-8" /> <html lang="ru">` // см. пункт1. +я думаю вы понимаете что `<meta>` должно находится в `<html><head>`
3. после подключения к бд `SET NAMES utf8`
4. `$name = iconv("ISO-8859-1","UTF-8",$row['name']);` // удалите это. Не сотит использовать функции конверта, если вы получаете данные из базы.
5. Проверить коллэйшн таблици и полей, должно везде быть что то типа `utf8_general_ci`, если это не так - то поменять.

На данном этапе, после этих правок всё должно работать правильно.
Если "кракозябры" всё еще имеют место быть - попробуйте из сайта добавить какую то строку в базу, а затем вывести её. Если строка отобразится нормально - значит у вас данные лежат в не верной кодировке. И нужно думать как исправить базу данных.

Comment: 1. Спасибо, буду знать
2. Да, само собой)
4. Ясно
5. Да везде utf_general_ci
новые строки отображаются корректно. Хостер берет дамп базы в txt, значит таблицы создаются и наполняются заново. Может в этом и была проблема? Но собственно уже решение найдено. Скорее всего версия mysql хостера более старая, и не понимает корректно mysqli_query

Comment: mysql_XXXX и mysqli_XXXX это просто разные модули для работы с базой данных mysql. mysqli новее и рекомендуется использовать именно этот модуль, так как mysql модуль более не поддерживается.

Answer (score 5):

По-моему, в новых версиях *PHP* работает только так:

```
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'db');
mysqli_set_charset($connection, 'utf8mb4');
```

Comment: Yuri. Спасибо, помогло.

Comment: я не смог добавить комментарий из за недостатка репы, но считаю важным подчеркнуть, что ответ пользователя shimon atanelov был единственным вариантом решения проблемы, который сработал у меня, когда я столкнулся с этой проблемой.
а ему ещё и минус поставил кто то! так что моя благодарность! может ещё кто то прочитает и найдёт решение своей проблемы.

Answer (score -1):

Открой конфиг mysql - my.ini
И добавь
[mysqld]
character-set-server = utf8

Answer (score -1):

а у меня заработало после этого: `mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci");`

Comment: в конце вопроса написано (фактически) то же самое. на «ответ», увы, не тянет.

Comment: да, я собственно и не претендую) просто у меня была та же проблема и решение `mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");` мне не помогло...